# Why I'm not getting multiple type result from Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I want more than one type result. In this example, I want both clothing stores and salons.

See my query:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + params[0] + "," + params[1] + "&radius=5000&type=clothing_store,beauty_salon&sensor=true&key=" + GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
```

I tried with `,` and `|` both. not getting result for multiple type.

**Note**: If I only use a single type, then I'm getting what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Place search documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), you're *generally* only permitted to specify a single type:

> `type` — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the list of supported types.

Comment: Okat. Thanks for the answer. but is there any hack? Like after first query, I again call second type query or something? I used Async Task and in do in background() I written that.

Comment: Yes, as far as I've understood regarding that API endpoint, you'll have to do two requests. :-)

Comment: Okay. Can you help me one more thing? Like from that response I'm able to get opening_hours, name. Like that what else I can get? can you tell me that list? Also I want a distance in KM, from my current location to a place which is coming from response. Need distance from All Places

Comment: You can see that list here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses - I reckon you'll have to calculate the distance yourself based on the coordinates in `params` and the ones in the response (under `geometry` -> `location`) :-)

Comment: Acha, But how will I calculate from latlong? I'm still not getting

Comment: Use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]) or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(Location). If you have any further questions regarding the distance calculation, you should probably create a new question here to keep this one focused. :-)

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark this as the answer so that future troubleshooters won't have to ask the question again! @ShefaliSingh

Comment: I accepted happily, and I'll try, otherwise tomorrow please help me